# How can I order mySql query having a Get method in between?

Tags: mysql, get, sql-order-by

I am trying to order my results of the following Query

```
$q_getPROVINCE = "select * from PROVINCES  WHERE CID =".$_GET['id'];
$r_getPROVINCE = mysql_query($q_getPROVINCE, $connection);
$n_getPROVINCE = mysql_num_rows($r_getPROVINCE);
```

it works perfectly but MY problem is that whenever I try to order it Im not sure how to write it, having the GET_ method in between.

```
$q_getPROVINCE = "select * from PROVINCES  WHERE CID =".$_GET['id']."ORDER BY CITY_EN ASC";
$r_getPROVINCE = mysql_query($q_getPROVINCE, $connection);
$n_getPROVINCE = mysql_num_rows($r_getPROVINCE);
```

I would appreciate your help...

Comment: on which field you want order by?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine may be you have give space between ORDER BY before " symbol. Try this

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a space before ORDER ? Like this :

```
$q_getPROVINCE = "select * from PROVINCES  WHERE CID =".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY CITY_EN ASC";
```